# Linux UIO driver include

Tags: yocto

i have a working yocto build on my system. 
I am trying to use the uio kernel driver.
Unfortunately I can't load it or find it. 
Do I have to include it in the config file during the build. 
I found the following option:

`CORE_IMAGE_EXTRA_INSTALL += "kernel-modules"`

Is this something that would add it to the build?

Comment: Please try find on Yocto Index site for "UID" recipe, maybe some of giving searches might be right for You - [Yocto Index: UID](http://layers.openembedded.org/layerindex/branch/master/recipes/?q=UIO).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done it using

```
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " kernel-module-<module-name>
KERNEL_MODULE_AUTOLOAD += "<module-name>"
```

It should work with the `CORE_IMAGE_EXTRA_INSTALL` instead of `IMAGE_INSTALL_append` which is kind of a hack.

If you are having trouble `bitbake -e <target>` will give you a full output of all variables and how they are set. You could check that output for CORE_IMAGE_EXTRA_INSTALL and make sure that your setting "takes".